# mysql fulltext search sort best results then sort again by other item

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, search, full-text-search

```
"SELECT *, 
    MATCH(md.keywords) AGAINST('$meta[keywords]') AS score
    FROM 
        meta_data AS md 
    INNER JOIN
        sites AS si ON md.domain = si.domain
    WHERE
        MATCH(md.keywords) AGAINST('$meta[keywords]')
    ORDER BY score DESC
    LIMIT 25"
```

I generated this query to find best matching results with fulltext keyword search. Now I want to sort these results again by most viewed entries. The views are also stored inside the mysql database in sites (si.views).

How can I first sort my results by best matching score and then sort these 25 best results by views? I think this will be done somehow with Grouping but I don't know how to get this working. Help would be appreciated. Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from 
(
    SELECT *, 
    MATCH(md.keywords) AGAINST('$meta[keywords]') AS score
    FROM 
        meta_data AS md 
    INNER JOIN
        sites AS si ON md.domain = si.domain
    WHERE
        MATCH(md.keywords) AGAINST('$meta[keywords]')
    ORDER BY score DESC
    LIMIT 25
) x
order by x.views
```

Comment: Hm, I get his error message: Warning: PDO::query() [pdo.query]: SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'id' in...

Comment: Instead of `SELECT *, MATCH...` you should name the columns you want to select by name.

Comment: Good point, thanks. But now I get this error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'x.views' in 'order clause'

Comment: You also have to put the `views` column in the inner select: `select si.views, ...`